# 2 absolute position xyz to relative between points

Tags: 3d, geometry, geocoding, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I Have two absolute xyz positions

first point-> x="2.08039166666667" y="41.4722694444444" z="128.71

and

second point->x="2.08039166666667" y="41.4723111111111" z="128.79"

both positions are absolute from 0 0 0

now if i change the center to first point  how i can get position from second point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the relative position of the second point from the first point, you'd subtract the first point from the second point (x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1).